# Sieve for making copy of email reaching a certain alias of an account

Tags: sieve

My email provider has support for the sieve language ([RFC 5228](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5228)) in *advanced mode* email filters, but [states](https://www.infomaniak.com/en/support/faq/1729/sort-incoming-e-mails-according-to-rules-sieve-filters) they "cannot provide additional support on this subject". I'd want to use sieve to improve my current email redirection strategy.

What would be a minimal sieve script such that when an email is somewhat sent to `foo@mydomain.fr`, which is an alias of my main email account `myself@mydomain.fr`, it's made a copy to `bar@mydomain.fr` (preferably: except if it's detectable from the headers that `bar@mydomain.fr` is already an addressee).

I can do *almost* that with their web-based (non-sieve) rule maker, by testing if the `To:` or `Cc:` field is (or contains) `foo@mydomain.fr`. However it's not robust. In particular it fails if the email is sent `Bcc: foo@mydomain.fr` (which is not among the fields I can specify) or via a redirection to `foo@mydomain.fr` (and I don't even know which field I could test for that).

Also, if the email is sent `To: foo@mydomain.fr` and `Cc: bar@mydomain.fr`, I'm afraid the later would receive the email twice.

---

Update: as suggested in a [helpful comment](https://serverfault.com/posts/comments/1499867), experiments shows that in what I get thru IMAP in the inbox for `myself@mydomain.fr` for something sent to it's alias as `Bcc: foo@mydomain.fr` (or even `Bcc: foo@anotherdomain.mx` redirecting to `foo@mydomain.fr`), something has helpfully added (on the second line)

```
Delivered-To: foo@mydomain.fr
```

So, assuming that a sieve script runs *after* that header is generated (I have no idea if that's the case), it may be that I need a minimal sieve script such that when `Delivered-To:` is `foo@mydomain.fr` the email gets copied to `bar@mydomain.fr` (preferably: only when neither `To:` nor `Cc:` includes `bar@mydomain.fr`)

I'm a seasoned programmer and postmaster, thus I see possible pitfalls in "includes". It should not be in the sense of string inclusion, should at least be case insensitive, and apply only to the email address without name. I'd like this (my first sieve script) to be as canonical as possible.

Comment: You might investigate the other headers of your mail messages. My mailserver for example sets an `X-Original-To:` header with the original e-mail recipient that was used in the SMTP (envelope) `RCPT TO` command when delivering the e-mail message to the SMTP server. That is the original recipient before expanding any local aliases and would be  `foo@mydomain.fr` even when that address is on the `BCC:` list and not included in the addresses of the message headers. My mailserver sets a second header `Delivered-To:` that is the recipient after expanding all local aliases and forwards.

Comment: In your example that would be `X-Original-To: foo@mydomain.fr`   `Delivered-To:  myself@mydomain.fr`

Comment: *"Also, if the email is sent to both foo@mydomain.fr and bar@mydomain.fr, I'm afraid the later would receive the email twice."*  That is impossible to prevent when  both are Bcc and may not even be something you really need to worry about otherwise either. When I sent myself messages with one alias on the To, another one the CC and a third on the Bcc line my mail server receives and stores three separate messages, that in my  e-mail client will be displayed as only one single message.

Comment: Other mail servers may set different headers though. That would take some testing if there is a viable approach there

Answer (score 0):

I seem to get about the desired effect with the following. But I welcome correction, simplification or improvement!

```
if allof (
  header :is "Delivered-To" "foo@mydomain.fr",
  not address :is :all "to" "bar@mydomain.fr",
  not address :is :all "cc" "bar@mydomain.fr"
  ) {
  redirect "bar@mydomain.fr";
  keep;
}
```

Comment: Will accept the answer only after more tests.